# Physics.OverlapSphere in Unity Mirror Networking

Tags: mirror

Someone has been able to use Physics.OverlapSphere in Mirror NetWorking, because no collider is detected for me, my project uses NetworkMatch, and if the NPC is with its correct Match and it collides with the Players correctly, it is just that I want to locate the closest player and To reduce the search for all players I want to do it only with those that are within the collision radius of Physics.OverlapSphere
without having to use a loop that consumes much more, but as I said, Physics.OverlapSphere does not pick up any collider, and I want to know if I should use it with Mirror Networking.

I was hoping to reduce searching for players with a Physics.OverlapSphere without having to loop through all the players in the scene.
but Physics.OverlapSphere is not recognizing the colliders in Mirror Networking.

Comment: I would like to thank you in advance for any help you can give me, I am about to launch and this problem is stopping me.